# MQTT messages not send mainflux Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, service, mqtt, nginx-ingress

I have setup mainflux on Kubernetes using this [link](https://mainflux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kubernetes/). Mainflux services are as follows after `kubectl get services -n mf`

```
NAME                                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                  AGE
mainflux-adapter-coap                                ClusterIP   10.245.219.210   <none>        5683/UDP                                 12h
mainflux-adapter-http                                ClusterIP   10.245.129.96    <none>        8185/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-auth                                        ClusterIP   10.245.32.62     <none>        8189/TCP,8181/TCP                        12h
mainflux-auth-headless                               ClusterIP   None             <none>        8189/TCP,8181/TCP                        12h
mainflux-envoy                                       ClusterIP   10.245.77.165    <none>        1883/TCP,8181/TCP,8183/TCP,8001/TCP      12h
mainflux-influxdb                                    ClusterIP   10.245.64.91     <none>        8086/TCP,8088/TCP                        12h
mainflux-influxdb-reader                             ClusterIP   10.245.54.239    <none>        8905/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-influxdb-writer                             ClusterIP   10.245.228.24    <none>        8900/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-jaeger-operator                             ClusterIP   10.245.222.151   <none>        8383/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-jaeger-operator-jaeger-agent                ClusterIP   None             <none>        5775/UDP,5778/TCP,6831/UDP,6832/UDP      12h
mainflux-jaeger-operator-jaeger-collector            ClusterIP   10.245.102.84    <none>        9411/TCP,14250/TCP,14267/TCP,14268/TCP   12h
mainflux-jaeger-operator-jaeger-collector-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        9411/TCP,14250/TCP,14267/TCP,14268/TCP   12h
mainflux-jaeger-operator-jaeger-query                ClusterIP   10.245.35.7      <none>        16686/TCP                                12h
mainflux-jaeger-operator-metrics                     ClusterIP   10.245.17.154    <none>        8383/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-mqtt                                        ClusterIP   None             <none>        1884/TCP,8081/TCP                        12h
mainflux-nats-client                                 ClusterIP   10.245.123.180   <none>        4222/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-nats-cluster                                ClusterIP   10.245.99.29     <none>        6222/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-nats-headless                               ClusterIP   None             <none>        4222/TCP,6222/TCP                        12h
mainflux-nats-monitoring                             ClusterIP   10.245.160.29    <none>        8222/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-postgresql-auth                             ClusterIP   10.245.156.246   <none>        5432/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-postgresql-auth-headless                    ClusterIP   None             <none>        5432/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-postgresql-things                           ClusterIP   10.245.229.117   <none>        5432/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-postgresql-things-headless                  ClusterIP   None             <none>        5432/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-postgresql-users                            ClusterIP   10.245.62.221    <none>        5432/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-postgresql-users-headless                   ClusterIP   None             <none>        5432/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-redis-auth-headless                         ClusterIP   None             <none>        6379/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-redis-auth-master                           ClusterIP   10.245.168.15    <none>        6379/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-redis-mqtt-headless                         ClusterIP   None             <none>        6379/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-redis-mqtt-master                           ClusterIP   10.245.60.43     <none>        6379/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-redis-streams-headless                      ClusterIP   None             <none>        6379/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-redis-streams-master                        ClusterIP   10.245.236.4     <none>        6379/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-things                                      ClusterIP   10.245.89.78     <none>        8182/TCP,8183/TCP,8989/TCP               12h
mainflux-things-headless                             ClusterIP   None             <none>        8182/TCP,8183/TCP,8989/TCP               12h
mainflux-ui                                          ClusterIP   10.245.228.83    <none>        3000/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-users                                       ClusterIP   10.245.5.152     <none>        8180/TCP                                 12h
mainflux-users-headless                              ClusterIP   None             <none>        8180/TCP                                 12h
```

Nginx ingress was installed also installed from [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/). I have not setup tls as explained in the last step. Appropriate ports are added in the ingress-nginx namespace and service:
ingress-nginx-controller like following.

```
  - name: mqtt
    port: 1883
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1883
  - name: mqtts
    port: 8883
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8883
```

Final ingress-nginx-controller is

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  uid: a5c635f6-be40-4f6c-bfb9-d9c12690283d
  resourceVersion: '3024805'
  creationTimestamp: '2022-01-07T19:57:31Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.1.0
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.0.13
  annotations:
    kubernetes.digitalocean.com/load-balancer-id: 3ed5e0cd-7beb-464e-8c04-c0d819fcea91
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
  finalizers:
    - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  managedFields:
    - manager: helm
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-01-07T19:57:31Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/version: {}
            f:helm.sh/chart: {}
        f:spec:
          f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
          f:ipFamilies: {}
          f:ipFamilyPolicy: {}
          f:ports:
            .: {}
            k:{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:appProtocol: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
            k:{"port":443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:appProtocol: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
          f:selector:
            .: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
          f:sessionAffinity: {}
          f:type: {}
    - manager: digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-01-07T20:00:02Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            f:kubernetes.digitalocean.com/load-balancer-id: {}
          f:finalizers:
            .: {}
            v:"service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup": {}
        f:status:
          f:loadBalancer:
            f:ingress: {}
    - manager: dashboard
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-01-08T17:06:46Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:spec:
          f:ports:
            k:{"port":1883,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
            k:{"port":8883,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      appProtocol: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
      nodePort: 31757
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      appProtocol: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
      nodePort: 32524
    - name: mqtt
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1883
      targetPort: 1883
      nodePort: 31382
    - name: mqtts
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8883
      targetPort: 8883
      nodePort: 30938
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  clusterIP: 10.245.197.161
  clusterIPs:
    - 10.245.197.161
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 143.198.250.146
```

Config map "tcp-services" looks like following

```
Data
{
    "1883": "mf/mainflux-envoy:1883",
    "8883": "mf/mainflux-nginx-internal:8883"
}
```

But when i try to send a test message via following command i get the following error

```
 mosquitto_pub -u 884bf934-68e0-42f6-b903-5d59f34250eb -P a7c3e321-eb3c-401a-ab9a-4e2f23aac286 -t channels/117800ea-9c1a-46f1-9b7b-7ef9f31c7a65/messages -h aqueglobal.baraq.pk -m '[{"bn":"some-base-name:","bt":1.276020076001e+09, "bu":"A","bver":5, "n":"voltage","u":"V","v":120.1}, {"n":"current","t":-5,"v":1.2}, {"n":"current","t":-4,"v":1.3}]'

Error: The connection was lost.

 mosquitto_pub -d -L mqtts://884bf934-68e0-42f6-b903-5d59f34250eb:a7c3e321-eb3c-401a-ab9a-4e2f23aac286@aqueglobal.baraq.pk:8883/channels/117800ea-9c1a-46f1-9b7b-7ef9f31c7a65/messages   -m "test-message"

Client null sending CONNECT
Error: Unknown error.
```

Comment: You are probably going to need to add a bunch more detail about how you have configured the none HTTP based ingress stuff here for anybody to be able to help.

Comment: let me add ingress-nginx-controller